# which method is better for network communication using java.net or java.nio for Android applications

Tags: java, android, java-io, socketchannel

I wanted to test which method I should use for performing network communication for my Android app. I want fastest network communication.

How should I test these two methods `java.net` and `java.nio` for my mobile app to get to the conclusion.

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're writing a server that expects to have tens of thousands of incoming connections there is no reason to prefer `java.nio` over `java.net`, and the latter is very much simpler to program.

I did very extensive benchmark testing with 1700 data points some years ago, which *inter alia* proved there was no performance difference between `java.net` and `java.nio` over single Internet connections.

Comment: How can I perform some benchmarks test to prove this ?

Comment: (a) Why? And (b) what don't you understand about how to perform benchmarks? Just test and measure.

Answer (score -1):

java.net method is better for network communication using java.net or java.nio for Android applications

Comment: How can I perform some benchmarks test to prove this ?

Comment: Your answer is incomprehensible.